# How can I access a property of a subclass on Xojo dynamically?

Tags: class, object, web-applications, properties, xojo

On a Xojo WebApp I created a `TextFieldClass` with a property "required as boolean".

On a webpage, I have some `TextFieldClass` objects.

What I want to do is simple… I want to do a `self.ControlCount` on the webpage, and check if all `textFieldClass` with the required property with "true" value in fact have contents in it.

Easy, right?…

```
Dim i as integer
Dim c As textFieldClass
For i=0 To self.ControlCount
    if self.ControlAtIndex(i) isa textFieldClass then
        **c=self.ControlAtIndex(i) // i got an error… expected class textFieldClass, but got class webObject…**
    End If
Next
```

And if I try:

```
Dim i as integer
Dim c As WebObject
For i=0 To self.ControlCount
    if self.ControlAtIndex(i) isa textFieldClass then
        c=self.ControlAtIndex(i)
        **if c.required then // I got an error… Type "WebObject" has no member named "required"**
            // do something here…
        end if
    End If
Next
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
c = TextFieldClass(self.ControlAtIndex(i))
```

Answer (score 1):

You were really close.  Since controlAtIndex brings back a RectControl you have to cast RectControl to the textFieldClass subclass.  Technically the same as above but with more explanation.

```
Dim i as integer
Dim c As WebObject
For i=0 To self.ControlCount-1 //Fixes mistake in original code.
    if self.ControlAtIndex(i) isa textFieldClass then
        c= textFieldClass(self.ControlAtIndex(i)) //Need to cast here
        if c.required then
            // do something here…
        end if
    End If
Next
```